# subscribe on click event is not working

Tags: meteor

My doc strucure:

```
"_id" : "p5NXQZd5b5dbMrECW",
"feed_id":"xfsfasfsadfdfafs",
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "user" : "fzkhiAArD4mgAAjbL",
            "comment" : "First comment",
            "commentedAt" : 1422416042795
        }, 
        {
            "user" : "fzkhiAArD4mgAAjbL",
            "comment" : " second comment",
            "commentedAt" : 1422416071633
        }, 
        {
            "user" : "fzkhiAArD4mgAAjbL",
            "comment" : " third comment is so longgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
            "commentedAt" : 1422416087707
        }, 
 .......
....
}
```

my code,Initially I'm sending 3 comments to the user using publish-composite

```
Meteor.publishComposite('hub_feed',function(hubid){ 
    return  {
        find: function() {
                return HubFeeds.find({hub_id:hubid});
        },
        children: [

            {
                find: function(feed) {
                    var res=FeedHits.findOne({feed_id:feed._id});
                    if(res){
                        if(_.has(res,"comments")){
                      return FeedHits.find({_id:res._id},{fields: {comments:{$slice: -3}}});
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

I'm subscribing in the client

```
Meteor.subscribe("hub_feed")
```

which is working fine and I displayed the 3 comments.

Now on click event I want to load more comments,so created another publish function

```
Meteor.publish("getExtraFeedComments",function(noOfComments,feedid){
            var required=noOfComments+10;
            ..........
            return FeedHits.find({feed_id:feedid},{fields: {comments:{$slice: -required}}});    
});
```

I'm subscribing to this publish function,when user clicks on **load more comments** button

```
'click #loadMoreComments':function(){
        var hasComments=FeedHits.findOne({feed_id:this._id});
        if(hasComments && _.has(hasComments,"comments")){
            var noOfComments=hasComments.comments.length;
            var handle=Meteor.subscribe("getExtraFeedComments",noOfComments,this._id);
            if(handle.ready()){
                console.log('ready');
                console.log(FeedHits.find().fetch());
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my issue, In console I'm not getting **ready** and also I'm getting only 3 comments.

why is this subscribe onclick event is not working.

**Nte**:In server before publishing I've checked the results .
It is displaying 5 comments,but in client it is showing only 3 comments

```
...........
......    
console.log(FeedHits.find({feed_id:feedid},{fields: {comments:{$slice: -required}}}).fetch())
    return FeedHits.find({feed_id:feedid},{fields: {comments:{$slice: -required}}});
```

**Edit**

with callback function

```
Meteor.subscribe("getExtraFeedComments",noOfComments,this._id,function(){
                        console.log(FeedHits.findOne({feed_id:self._id}));
            });
```

I'm getting 3 values only I'm not getting more values

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to do a synchronous call from the client:

```
var handle=Meteor.subscribe("getExtraFeedComments",noOfComments,this._id);
```

In Meteor the client is never synchronous, so in this case 'handle' will not return what you expect. It probably will be null.

In order to accomplish what you are trying to do, you need a callback in your subscribe function.

```
Meteor.subscribe("getExtraFeedComments", function(){ /* sub ready here */})
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: regardless of synchronous or async the data shoul be sent to the client , but   here I'm not getting latest data to client

Comment: put your console.logs in a proper callback... do they still not fire and report what you expect?

Comment: but on the function call back also it is returning 3 results

Comment: the issues is in the publish then. try using 'limit' instead of slice... or check your publish function before you return it.